# Load remote image from static html in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-assets

I have an Android app that uses a WebView with static html with custom css and javascript, all loaded from local assets. I also need to display some images in the html that are not in local assets, but they must be downloaded.

All local resources (css, javascript and static images) are all correctly loaded and rendered. Instead remote resources are not downloaded. In particular, I get the following error when I try to download an image from the web:

> Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid xxx

In AndroidManifest.xml internet access has been granted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the layout of the Activity with the WebView:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This is the code that initializes the WebView:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This is the point in which the static html is loaded:

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", CHARSET, null);
```

I need to use `loadDataWithBaseURL` because there are many css and javascript resources that need to remain local in the assets folder.

How can I manage to show remote images? Remote images should be loaded in the html by a javascript code.

Comment: show, how you link the image from the web.

Comment: I link image in a img tag `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />` or as background with jQuery `$('#product').css("background-image","url('http://www.example.com/image.jpg')")`

Comment: your approach looks correct for me, I don't think I can see anything wrong.

Comment: It was a problem of Android emulator. I've tried it on a real device and it works.